# ¿Es posible agregar listas a un diccionario de forma ordenada o en la posición deseada?

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

Tengo una lista que incluye listas con numero del mes, el día y un evento, de este tipo:

```
months = [[3, 21, "evento"], [6, 4, "evento"], [1, 15, "evento"], [2, 18, "evento"], [5, 7, "evento"], [4, 11, "evento"],
      [3, 14, "evento"], [6, 6, "evento"], [1, 30, "evento"], [2, 1, "evento"], [5, 4, "evento"], [4, 8, "evento"]]
```

Actualmente estoy usando este método para pasarlo a un diccionario ordenando los días:

```
events = {}

for value in months:
    month = value[0]
    day = value[1]

    if not month in events:
        events[month] = []

    if len(events[month]) == 0:
        events[month].append([day, value[2]])

    else:
        for d in range(len(events[month])):
            if day < events[month][0][0]:
                events[month].insert(0, [day, value[2]])
            else:
                events[month].insert(d+1, [day, value[2]])
```

Quizás me esté complicando con la forma, no tengo suficiente conocimiento para optimizarlo más o hacerlo de una forma más elegante, pero por lo pronto me resuelve uno de los problemas.

La duda es, **¿es posible agregar los meses al diccionario de forma ordenada de menor a mayor?**

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si quieres ordenar los elementos existentes varios algoritmos de ordenamiento, o puedes utilizar la función ```sorted()``` además puedes mejorar el ciclo for

Comment: Recuerda que lo diccionarios clásicos no tienen ningún orden.

Comment: A partir de Python 3.7 se garantiza un orden en los diccionarios, que es el orden en que se hayan creado las entradas en el diccionario. Por tanto si vas añadiendo al diccionario las claves en un cierto orden, en ese mismo orden las recuperarás luego cuando iteres por el diccionario.

Answer (score 0):

Era más fácil de lo que pensaba, estaba cogiendo el enfoque incorrecto, mejor ordenar primero los meses y luego los días.

```
def element(elem):
    return elem[0]

sorted_months = sorted(months, key=element)
events = {}

for value in sorted_months:
    month = value[0]
    day = value[1]
    if not month in events:
        events[month] = []
    events[month].append([day, value[2]])

for e in events:
    sorted_day = sorted(events[e], key=element)
    events[e] = sorted_day
```

Creo que así mejor, más simple. Y seguro se puede simplificar aún más.

Muchas gracias!!